# Javascript - easy way to split/devide string by pattern into N parts where last part is rest of the string

Tags: javascript, string, split

If i have the strings:

```
string1 = "1 secondpart this is the third part"
string2 = "14   secondpartagain   third part   again"
```

and i want to split them by a pattern (like whitespace) into N parts (like 3 parts), then the result should be something like:

```
part1: "1", part2: "secondpart", part3: "this is the third part"
  -and
part1: "14", part2: "secondpartagain", part3: "third part   again"
```

In Ruby i would do something like:

```
part1, part2, part3= string1.split(/\s+/, 3)
```

If i use the split function in Javascript i get something like this:

```
var myArray1 = string1.split(/\s+/, 3);
var myArray2 = string2.split(/\s+/, 3);

myArray1[0]: "1", myArray1[1]: "secondpart", myArray1[2]: "this"
  -and
myArray2[0]: "14", myArray2[1]: "secondpartagain", myArray2[2]: "third"
```

What is the easiest way to split a string by a pattern into N parts where last part is rest of the string?

Comment: You're probably going to need to use indexOf and split by the location of the \s@ (first two) and substring the rest.

Comment: To everybody: it must work for string2 also. That is, the last part of the string must not be manipulated, for example by replacing several whitespace chars by single spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split on the first two (groups of) whitespace:

```
function splitString(text) {
    var rexSplitter = /^(\S*)\s+(\S*)\s+(.*)$/,
        match = rexSplitter.exec(text);
    if (match) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(match, 1, 3);
    } 
}
```

or, if you’re into short code:

```
function splitString(text) {
     var match = /^(\S*)\s+(\S*)\s+(.*)$/.exec(text);
     return match && Array.prototype.slice.call(match, 1, 3);
}
```

Comment: This is not general but okay in my case, since i know that num_parts=3 and pattern=whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you like one liners you could do this:

```
var str = "1 secondpart this is the third part";
var arr = str.split(/\s+/,2).concat(str.replace(/^\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+/,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function partitioner(original, pattern, num_parts, c) {
    var parts = original.split(pattern);
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < num_parts - 1 && parts.length > 0; i++) {
        var part = parts.shift();
        result.push(part);
    }

    result.push(parts.join(c));

    return result;
}

var string1 = "1 secondpart this is the third part";
var splitted = partitioner(string1, /\s+/, 3, ' ');
console.log(splitted);
```

Comment: slight overkill don't you think?

Comment: It is acutally a nice attempt to create a general solution. Look at my other answer; it is inspired by this one by Björn.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the original question. In my specific case is num_parts=3 and divide_pattern=whitespace. In that case, Martijns answer is okay.

Björns attempt to make a general solution is also okay - but in the last part of the string, the multible whitespaces are unfortunately replaced by single spaces.

I have made a combination of the 2 former answers, which should work as some sort of generalt Split-function. This one accepts Words but can easily be modified to accept other patterns:

```
function divideString(orig_string, divide_pat, num_parts) {
    var regExPattern = /^\s*/.source;
    for (var i = 0; i < num_parts - 1; i++) {
        regExPattern += /(\w+)/.source + divide_pat.source;
    }
    regExPattern += /(.*)$/.source;
    var re = new RegExp(regExPattern); 

    var match = re.exec(orig_string);
    if (match) {
        return match.slice(1, num_parts+1);
    }
}

var string2 = "14   secondpartagain   third part   again";

alert( divideString(string2, /\s+/, 3) );
```

Answer (score -2):

See java docs on string splitting:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

It should do what you need, and I am 100% sure this works in java script.

```
var s="1 secondpart this is the third part";
        var d=s.split(" ");
        var l=d.length;
        document.writeln("<p> Length:"+l+"</p>");
        for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
            document.writeln("<p> "+i+":"+d[i]+"</p>");
        }

        document.writeln("<p> End </p>");
```

Comment: He's asking for Javascript, not for Java.

Comment: I am sorry i wrote java, not java script, I have updated my  answer